# Como colorir linhas no RStudio / R com seasonplot

Tags: r, plot

Olá, tenho essa série de dados e preciso que cada linha contínua dessa tenha uma cor diferente da outra, de modo que seja fácil identificar cada uma delas.
Qual comando que posso usar para fazer isso?

Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```r
seasonplot(dados.ts, axis(2, at=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)))
```

E estou conseguindo o gráfico seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

O argumento a ser usado para colocar cores é `col`. Ao usar `col = 1:12`, eu pedi ao R para utilizar as 12 primeiras cores em sua paleta padrão.

```r
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
seasonplot(AirPassengers, col = 1:12)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

É possível escolher individualmente cada cor por seu nome. Para isso, o argumento a ser usado é `col = c("cor01", "cor02", ..., "cor12")` no meu exemplo, que necessita de 12 cores. Uma lista completa das cores já implementadas no R padrão pode ser obtida através do comando `colors()`.

Entretanto, o gráfico criado continua confuso, pois não há identificação do que cada cor significa. É necessário colocar uma legenda com o comando `legend`:

```r
seasonplot(AirPassengers, col = 1:12)
legend("topleft", 
       legend = c( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"),
       col = 1:12,
       pch = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Essa legenda deve ser colocada manualmente. Inclusive, o próprio usuário deve checar se as cores das linhas correspondem às cores informadas na legenda.